# Does ext4 filesystem in read-only mode has better performance for mobile devices then ext2?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-source, ext4, ext2

*Android* [uses](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/search?q=ext4&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=device) `ext4` file system for read-only partitions, but in my opinion for flash read-only drives `ext2` is more appropriate, because it does not have performance overhead and safe for using without write operation.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does *Android* use `ext4` file system for read-only partitions?

Not really an expert here and probably won't give a specific answer but, as you surely know, *Android* heavily leans on *Linux* and the choice might have been *Linux*-dictated.

The [great work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0991055527) by [*Jonathan Levin*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734439/technologeeks) which has lately become [free](http://newandroidbook.com/AIvI-M-RL1.pdf) and which I strongly recommend you to get familiar with states the following*:

*"[Android enforces no constraints as to the filesystem types](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2697069), but eMMC and MMC devices presently use the Linux Ext4 filesystem (as of Gingerbread, in place of the older YAFFS system), since the storage layer exports a block device. Ext4 has become the default filesystem in Linux as of 2.6.27, and is a well tested filesystem, albeit not a necessarily flash-optimized one."*

---

<sup>* Chapter II -> Partitioning Scheme -> File Systems</sup>

Also `ext4` without using journal [has better](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0390131ba84fd3f726f9e24fc4553828125700bb) performance then `ext2`:

```
                    ext2      ext4, default  ext4, no journal  
initial writes    13.0 MB/s     15.4 MB/s      15.7 MB/s  
rewrites          13.1 MB/s     15.6 MB/s      15.9 MB/s  
reads             15.2 MB/s     16.9 MB/s      17.2 MB/s  
re-reads          15.3 MB/s     16.9 MB/s      17.2 MB/s  
re-reads          15.3 MB/s     16.9 MB/s      17.2 MB/s
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the true answer, but here are some possibilities.

`ext4` has improvements over `ext2` even in read-only mode, such as using extents rather than block maps. This saves on metadata overhead.

The system partition can be remounted read-write on rooted devices, and during system updates (except on *Nougat*+ devices using two system partitions for seamless updates). `ext4` generally has better allocation behavior than `ext2`.

The filesystems may be created with `-O ^has_journal`, which removes the overhead of journaling from ext4. (See the `-j` option to `mkuserimg_mke2fs.sh`.)

Also, given that `ext4` is already in use for the read-write user partition, I suspect there would be a tendency to avoid `ext2` just to reduce the total amount of different code that is being run (and needs to be tested). Some ports unset `CONFIG_EXT2_FS` to shrink the kernel. (`ext2` filesystems can still be mounted using the `ext4` driver, although I don't expect this to be done.)